# Asp.Net Identity Claims Table Not Created

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Did I mess up the normal table creation by implementing my own mapping to the our existing user table? When running the application the normal AspNet tables are not generated in the database.

I was able to figure out how to map the AspNetUsers table to our existing table in our database using the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("DBUser");

        var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>();

        entity.HasKey(x => x.UserID);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.Id);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumber);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.EmailConfirmed);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnabled);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.LockoutEndDateUtc);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumber);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.SecurityStamp);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.TwoFactorEnabled);
        entity.Ignore(x => x.AccessFailedCount);

        entity.Property(x => x.UserID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        entity.Property(x => x.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");            
}
```

However, when I run the application and register a user for the first time, the normally created AspNet prefixed tables like UserClaims, UserLogins, UserRoles, and Roles are not created for some reason, and it does insert a record into my DBUser table with the correct information.

Since I'm using an existing database, should I assume that I need to manually create these tables?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how to do your data migration ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. Let me clarify more on what I'm asking. Did I mess up the normal table creation by implementing my own mapping to the our existing user table?